# How can I make a flashloan bot

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, flash-loans, aave, sushiswap

How Can I make a flash loan bot which can operate on `Aave`, `uniswap`, `sushiswap` etc? I know a [furucombo](https://furucombo.app/), but this is too complicated for me. My Idea is the bot will keep an eye on certain tokens & automatically execute the arbitrage. It will not be limited to 2 or 3 tokens. It can do multiple swaps. I solved a CTF challenge [arbitrage](https://quillctf.super.site/challenges/arbitrage) (my approach: https://aviksaikatka-blog-posts.netlify.app/quillctf/arbitrage/) where I generated all possible swaps to get the most profitable swap using the `swapExactTokensForTokens` method `uniswap` vs(`ISwapV2Router02`). But I want it to work on multiple platforms not just limited to `uniswap`.

Comment: Start with one platform, them modify the bot to support two and so on.

Comment: I have no idea where to start. Can you suggest me some resources?

Comment: You have started fine. You'll have to study contracts for the other AMM. It is a very competitive environment, you can find generic stuff, but it is unlikely that someone will share the state of the art.